# Break up block in several parts

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I basically want to break up the ADC block on the right hand side of this figure:

[image]

I want it to be broken into 4 parts. That means one part for each line that it is connected to. One I/O for each ADC block.

The code is below:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\usetikzlibrary{chains,fit,positioning}
\begin{document}

% Version 3
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 20mm and 5mm,
  start chain = going right,
 block/.style = {draw, minimum height=20mm, minimum width=5mm,
                 font=\boldmath,on chain}]
% upper blocks
\node (ht1)   [block,draw=none]
{\hphantom{$\boldmath(H)^+$}};
\node (f1)    [block,right=6mm of ht1]     {$T^{-1}$};
\node (y1)    [block,right=39mm of ht1]     {$T$};
\node (adc1)  [block]                       {ADC};
% lower blocks
\node (ht2)   [block,draw=none,below=of ht1]
{\hphantom{$\boldmath(H)^+$}};
\node (f2)    [block,right=6mm of ht2]     {$T^{-1}$};
\node (y2)    [block,right=39mm of ht2]     {$T$};
\node (adc2)  [block]                       {ADC};
% common input nodes
\node (in2)   [draw,inner sep=0pt, fit=(ht1)  (ht2),label=center:$\boldmath H^+$] {};
% top blocks
    \node (cpu) [above=15mm of in2]     {CPU};
    \node (rf)  [above=15mm of y1]      {RF-chain};

% Math symbols
    %\node at (42mm,15mm) (g1) {$\boldmath Y_1$};

    \node (Y) at (53mm,18mm) {$\boldmath Y_1$};
    \draw [->] (Y) -- (53mm,10mm);

    \node (Y2) at (53mm,-23mm) {$\boldmath Y_k$    
};
    \draw [->] (Y2) -- (53mm,-30mm);

    \node (Z) at (41mm,6mm) {$\boldmath Z_1$};
    \node (Z2) at (41mm,-34mm) {$\boldmath Z_k$};

    \node (x) at (-12mm,11mm) {$\boldmath \hat{x}$};

\draw[densely dotted] ([xshift=29mm] cpu.north -| in2.east) coordinate (in3)
                    -- (in3 |- in2.south);
% lines between blocks
    \foreach \y in {-0.75, -0.25, 0.25, 0.75}
{
% 8 input lines
    \draw [->]  ([yshift=\y cm +2 cm] in2.west)--++(180:1cm);
    \draw [->]  ([yshift=\y cm -2 cm] in2.west)--++(180:1cm);
}
% 2 lines between other blocks
    \foreach \j in {1, 2}
{
        \foreach \y  in {-0.25, 0.25, 0.75, -0.75}
        {
            \foreach \i [remember=\i as \lasti (initially y\j)] in {adc\j}
    \draw [<-] ([yshift= \y cm ]\lasti.east)--([yshift=\y cm]\i.west);
    \draw (-1,-2.0) circle [radius=0.7pt,yshift=-0 cm -\y cm];
    \draw (3.95,-2.0) circle [radius=0.7pt,yshift=-0 cm -\y cm];
    %\draw (0,-1) -- (4,-1);
    %\draw ([yshift= 0.5 cm -\y cm] adc\j.east)--++(0:1+1.5*\y)   node[antenna] {};
    \draw ([yshift=-0 cm -\y cm] adc\j.east)--++([xshift=1.5cm] 0:1+1.5*\y)   node[antenna] {};
    }

    \foreach \y  in {-0.25, 0.25}
        {
            \foreach \i [remember=\i as \lasti (initially f\j)] in { y\j}
    \draw [<-] ([yshift= \y cm ]\lasti.east)--([yshift=\y cm]\i.west);
    }

    \foreach \y  in {-0.25, 0.25, 0.75, -0.75}
        {
            \foreach \i [remember=\i as \lasti (initially ht\j)] in { f\j}
    \draw [<-] ([yshift= \y cm ]\lasti.east)--([yshift=\y cm]\i.west);
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Maybe it can be directly manipulated in the line:

```
\node (adc1)  [block]      {ADC};
```

Comment: What should happen with the label `ADC`? Do you want it printed in each of the four parts?

Comment: The ADC label should be printed for each of the four parts.

Comment: @Bob1990 Why are you using `on chain` in `block`?

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion. I start by defining a new style `block4` that is a `rectangle split` type node, i.e. a rectangular node with multiple parts. The `shapes.multipart` library is loaded because of this. In the `adc` nodes, change the style from `block` to `block4`, and the node label to `ADC\nodepart{two}ADC\nodepart{three}ADC\nodepart{four}ADC`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\usetikzlibrary{chains,fit,positioning,shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}

% Version 3t
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 20mm and 5mm,
  start chain = going right,
  block/.style = {draw, minimum height=20mm, minimum width=5mm,
                 font=\boldmath,on chain},
  block4/.style={block,rectangle split,rectangle split parts=4}]
% upper blocks
\node (ht1)   [block,draw=none]
{\hphantom{$\boldmath(H)^+$}};
\node (f1)    [block,right=6mm of ht1]     {$T^{-1}$};
\node (y1)    [block,right=39mm of ht1]     {$T$};
\node (adc1)  [block4] {ADC\nodepart{two}ADC\nodepart{three}ADC\nodepart{four}ADC};
% lower blocks
\node (ht2)   [block,draw=none,below=of ht1]
{\hphantom{$\boldmath(H)^+$}};
\node (f2)    [block,right=6mm of ht2]     {$T^{-1}$};
\node (y2)    [block,right=39mm of ht2]     {$T$};
\node (adc2)  [block4] {ADC\nodepart{two}ADC\nodepart{three}ADC\nodepart{four}ADC};
% common input nodes
\node (in2)   [draw,inner sep=0pt, fit=(ht1)  (ht2),label=center:$\boldmath H^+$] {};
% top blocks
    \node (cpu) [above=15mm of in2]     {CPU};
    \node (rf)  [above=15mm of y1]      {RF-chain};

% Math symbols
    %\node at (42mm,15mm) (g1) {$\boldmath Y_1$};

    \node (Y) at (53mm,18mm) {$\boldmath Y_1$};
    \draw [->] (Y) -- (53mm,10mm);

    \node (Y2) at (53mm,-23mm) {$\boldmath Y_k$    
};
    \draw [->] (Y2) -- (53mm,-30mm);

    \node (Z) at (41mm,6mm) {$\boldmath Z_1$};
    \node (Z2) at (41mm,-34mm) {$\boldmath Z_k$};

    \node (x) at (-12mm,11mm) {$\boldmath \hat{x}$};

\draw[densely dotted] ([xshift=29mm] cpu.north -| in2.east) coordinate (in3)
                    -- (in3 |- in2.south);
% lines between blocks
    \foreach \y in {-0.75, -0.25, 0.25, 0.75}
{
% 8 input lines
    \draw [->]  ([yshift=\y cm +2 cm] in2.west)--++(180:1cm);
    \draw [->]  ([yshift=\y cm -2 cm] in2.west)--++(180:1cm);
}
% 2 lines between other blocks
    \foreach \j in {1,2}
{
        \foreach \y/\anchor  in {-0.25/two east, 0.25/three east, 0.75/four east, -0.75/text east}
        {
            \foreach \i [remember=\i as \lasti (initially y\j)] in {adc\j}
    \draw [<-] ([yshift= \y cm ]\lasti.east)--([yshift=\y cm]\i.west);
    \draw (-1,-2.0) circle [radius=0.7pt,yshift=-0 cm -\y cm];
    \draw (3.95,-2.0) circle [radius=0.7pt,yshift=-0 cm -\y cm];
    %\draw (0,-1) -- (4,-1);
    %\draw ([yshift= 0.5 cm -\y cm] adc\j.east)--++(0:1+1.5*\y)   node[antenna] {};
    \draw ([yshift=-0 cm -\y cm] adc\j.east)--++([xshift=1.5cm] 0:1+1.5*\y)   node[antenna] {};
    }

    \foreach \y  in {-0.25, 0.25}
        {
            \foreach \i [remember=\i as \lasti (initially f\j)] in { y\j}
    \draw [<-] ([yshift= \y cm ]\lasti.east)--([yshift=\y cm]\i.west);
    }

    \foreach \y  in {-0.25, 0.25, 0.75, -0.75}
        {
            \foreach \i [remember=\i as \lasti (initially ht\j)] in { f\j}
    \draw [<-] ([yshift= \y cm ]\lasti.east)--([yshift=\y cm]\i.west);
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution. It keeps `phantom` adc1 and adc2 nodes because they are later used to draw connections. But when connections are drawn an individual node is added.

I've also changed the inner `foreach` condition.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\usetikzlibrary{chains,fit,positioning}
\begin{document}

% Version 3
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 20mm and 5mm,
  start chain = going right,
 block/.style = {draw, minimum height=20mm, minimum width=5mm,
                 font=\boldmath,on chain}]
% upper blocks
\node (ht1)   [block,draw=none]
{\hphantom{$\boldmath(H)^+$}};
\node (f1)    [block,right=6mm of ht1]     {$T^{-1}$};
\node (y1)    [block,right=39mm of ht1]     {$T$};
\node (adc1)  [block, draw=none]                       {\phantom{ADC}};
% lower blocks
\node (ht2)   [block,draw=none,below=of ht1]
{\hphantom{$\boldmath(H)^+$}};
\node (f2)    [block,right=6mm of ht2]     {$T^{-1}$};
\node (y2)    [block,right=39mm of ht2]     {$T$};
\node (adc2)  [block, draw=none]                       {\phantom{ADC}};
% common input nodes
\node (in2)   [draw,inner sep=0pt, fit=(ht1)  (ht2),label=center:$\boldmath H^+$] {};
% top blocks
    \node (cpu) [above=15mm of in2]     {CPU};
    \node (rf)  [above=15mm of y1]      {RF-chain};

% Math symbols
    %\node at (42mm,15mm) (g1) {$\boldmath Y_1$};

    \node (Y) at (53mm,18mm) {$\boldmath Y_1$};
    \draw [->] (Y) -- (53mm,10mm);

    \node (Y2) at (53mm,-23mm) {$\boldmath Y_k$    
};
    \draw [->] (Y2) -- (53mm,-30mm);

    \node (Z) at (41mm,6mm) {$\boldmath Z_1$};
    \node (Z2) at (41mm,-34mm) {$\boldmath Z_k$};

    \node (x) at (-12mm,11mm) {$\boldmath \hat{x}$};

\draw[densely dotted] ([xshift=29mm] cpu.north -| in2.east) coordinate (in3)
                    -- (in3 |- in2.south);
% lines between blocks
    \foreach \y in {-0.75, -0.25, 0.25, 0.75}
{
% 8 input lines
    \draw [->]  ([yshift=\y cm +2 cm] in2.west)--++(180:1cm);
    \draw [->]  ([yshift=\y cm -2 cm] in2.west)--++(180:1cm);
}
% 2 lines between other blocks
    \foreach \j in {1, 2}
{
        \foreach \y  in {-0.25, 0.25, 0.75, -0.75}
        {
            \foreach \i  in {adc\j}
    \draw [<-] ([yshift= \y cm ]y\j.east)--([yshift=\y cm]\i.west) node[draw, minimum height=3.5mm, anchor=west]{ADC};
    \draw (-1,-2.0) circle [radius=0.7pt,yshift=-0 cm -\y cm];
    \draw (3.95,-2.0) circle [radius=0.7pt,yshift=-0 cm -\y cm];
    %\draw (0,-1) -- (4,-1);
    %\draw ([yshift= 0.5 cm -\y cm] adc\j.east)--++(0:1+1.5*\y)   node[antenna] {};
    \draw ([yshift=-0 cm -\y cm] adc\j.east) --++([xshift=1.5cm] 0:1+1.5*\y)   node[antenna] {};
    }

    \foreach \y  in {-0.25, 0.25}
        {
            \foreach \i [remember=\i as \lasti (initially f\j)] in { y\j}
    \draw [<-] ([yshift= \y cm ]\lasti.east)--([yshift=\y cm]\i.west);
    }

    \foreach \y  in {-0.25, 0.25, 0.75, -0.75}
        {
            \foreach \i [remember=\i as \lasti (initially ht\j)] in { f\j}
    \draw [<-] ([yshift= \y cm ]\lasti.east)--([yshift=\y cm]\i.west);
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

A detail:

[image]